# The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Authentication failed, see inner exception. in restclient

Tags: .net-core

I am getting below error when I call the API using restclient C#.net in windows server.
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Authentication failed, see inner exception. The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Authentication failed, see inner exception. Can anyone suggests how to fix the error.

```
 var client = new RestClient(RefreshTokenUrl + "?refresh_token=" + RefreshToken + "&client_id=" + ClientID + "&client_secret=" + SecreateClientID + "&redirect_uri=" + objProps.Redirecturl + "&grant_type=refresh_token");
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
              
                var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest to resolve this issue.